# Parsing &[u8] or &str to rug::Integer using rug::Integer::parse()

Tags: rust

[`rug::Integer::parse`](https://docs.rs/rug/1.9.0/rug/struct.Integer.html#method.parse) works with string literals (`&'static str`) as shown:

```
use rug::{Integer, Assign};

fn main() {
    let n = "12";
    let mut id = Integer::new();
    id.assign(Integer.parse(n).unwrap()); // This works 
}
```

However, it doesn't work with `&str`:

```
use rug::{Integer, Assign};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let n = vec![0u8, 1, 2];
    let s = str::from_utf8(&n).unwrap();
    let mut id = Integer::new();
    id.assign(Integer.parse(s).unwrap()); // This works 
}
```

Or with `&[u8]`:

```
use rug::{Integer, Assign};

fn main() {
    let n = vec![0u8, 1, 2];
    let mut id = Integer::new();
    id.assign(Integer.parse(&n[..]).unwrap()); // This works 
}
```

In the latter two cases, the error is:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseIntegerError { kind: InvalidDigit }
```

Not sure what is going on given that `parse` is supposed to work with both `&str` and `&[u8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rug::Integer::parse` works with a UTF-8 string. While it accepts `&[u8]`, the integers in the slice are parsed as the bytes of a UTF-8 string.

The string "12" as an array of bytes is `[49, 50]`, so if you want to parse like that, you'd have to use those bytes.

```rust
use rug::{Assign, Integer};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let n = vec![49, 50];
    let s = str::from_utf8(&n).unwrap();
    let mut id = Integer::new();
    id.assign(Integer::parse(s).unwrap());

    assert_eq!(id, Integer::from(12));
}
```

The Rust Playground doesn't have the `rug` crate, so [here's a simplified version.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=351bce56ba299c90ff070e9a0c7d2f23)

Parsing `[0, 1, 2]` directly doesn't make sense with `Integer::parse` since the UTF-8 codepoints corresponding to `0` `1` and `2` aren't digits. Instead, they're [the three non-printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), [SOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) and [STX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX).

---

On the other hand, if you have an array of base 256 digits and want to convert it to `rug::Integer`, consider using [`rug::Integer::from_digits`](https://docs.rs/rug/1.9.0/rug/struct.Integer.html#method.from_digits) or [`rug::Integer::assign_digits`](https://docs.rs/rug/1.9.0/rug/struct.Integer.html#method.assign_digits). By using other integer types, you can get other bases. For example, using `u16` digits will be interpreted as base `2^16`.

```rust
use rug::{integer::Order, Integer};

fn main() {
    let n = vec![0u8, 1, 2];
    let id = Integer::from_digits(&n[..], Order::Msf);
    assert_eq!(id, Integer::from(0 * 256 * 256 + 1 * 256 + 2));
}
```

---

Finally, if you have an array of base ten digits, you could convert to a string first and then use [`rug::Integer::from_str_radix`.](https://docs.rs/rug/1.9.0/rug/struct.Integer.html#method.from_str_radix) There doesn't seem to be any direct conversion in the `rug::Integer` API, so you'd have to either implement it yourself with arithmetic operations or use this less-than-optimal solution.

```
use rug::Integer;

fn main() {
    let n = vec![0_u8, 1, 2];
    let n_str: String = n.iter().map(|d| d.to_string()).collect();
    assert_eq!(n_str, "012");

    let id = Integer::from_str_radix(&n_str, 10).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(id, Integer::from(12));
}
```

Comment: What I am really trying to do is generate a random 128-bit binary number and parse it as a decimal: https://gist.github.com/rust-play/2b508e0bc10235f7e8b1545994d2eb1a.

Would you have any ideas on this?

Comment: @picotard `Integer` has a `From` implementation for all the primitive integer types, so you can use `getrandom` as you are, convert the result to `u128` with [`u128::from_ne_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u128.html#method.from_ne_bytes) and then use `Integer::from`. Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d53cb46bf1107848bf1bd7cb6925d33f).

Comment: I'm so sorry, the 128-bit was just a placeholder value. It's actually for generating any 128 to 256 bit binary number. So something like 182, or 190 etc would also need to work.

Comment: @picotard Then the `from_digits` that I mentioned in the answer is what you want (and that would have worked for specifically 128 bits too). If you need the number of bits to be not be a non-multiple of 8, just mask the highest byte to zero the excess bits.

Comment: I was initially confused with base 256, re-reading it, it makes perfect sense, thanks!